# How can I remove my ban on asking questions?

Tags: discussion

How can I remove my ban on asking questions? My asked questions are closed.

Comment: This question has some later-asked-and-closed duplicates.  The one at http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5942/why-am-i-not-able-to-ask-any-more-questions has a comment by Iain which I think is insightful, valuable, and adds to the debate, so I'm posting this comment in case people want to click through and read it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are getting the message:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account

Then [you need to see this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) for detailed information on why you're banned and what you can do about it.

In short:

- There is an automatic filter that will ban questions and/or answers from IP addresses or accounts with a history of extremely poor posts.
- The details of the filter are secret, but it is partly based on downvotes.  If your questions and/or answers are getting many downvotes, you are likely to be banned.
- Deleted questions and deleted answers count towards the automatic ban.  If a large percentage of your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they were not suitable for the site.
- In order to get un-banned, you need to edit some of your existing questions and/or answers to improve them.
- Again, the details of the banning algorithm are secret, but it's been strongly hinted by SE staff that if you're banned from asking *questions,* posting some good *answers* may help get you un-banned.
- The "ban" is actually a severe rate limit: in order to give you a slight chance of lifting the ban, you are allowed to ask one question every 6 months.  If you ask a good question that gets some upvotes, it may be enough to lift the ban.

Comment: Looking at the evidence, this is most likely to be the poster's problem. This is a hard box to get out of.

Comment: I just discovered I'm banned too. I think you guys have taken a rather militant stance on this. Why is it that when you down vote that you're not FORCED to explain why? I asked a very simple question because I'd researched it but was getting conflicting answers. It was downvoted but I can't see by who and they're not explaining why!

Comment: *I think you guys have taken a rather militant stance on this.* - these bans are automated. Nothing to do with either high rep members or even the mods. *Why is it that when you down vote that you're not FORCED to explain why?* You've been pointed towards meta.stackoverflow as an authoratative source for this but one simple reason: if you force people to comment as part of a vote then either people won't vote (which is bad) or they'll comment with something like 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' which is no better than no comment at all.

Comment: Just wondering: you all use terms such as "poor quality", which is a rather subjective term. When it is all about some votes (not many). I only suspect it's possible that even some veterans here could let their friends know (totally legit) about their questions, to eventually vote them up. I'm not talking about fake accounts, voting rings, fiverr paid people or armies of spammers. But why was this possible method never mentioned in current context?