# I don't understand why a question is not a REAL question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked a simple question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/460231/redirect-mysql-queries-to-another-server)

> How can I redirect MySQL queries to another server?

Now my topic is closed, I don't understand why? because It's related to MySQL, MySQl-Sever and server stuff. I even got three answers that solved my problem too.

If it's not a real question then why those people spend their time to answer?

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is
> ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot
> be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this
> question so that it can be reopened

How is it difficult to tell when I get three answers? And what to clarify when the problem is solved? a lot of people might have this question!

The worst thing is that I can no longer ask questions. I'm banned!

I edited my question but you can still see the revision.

Answer (score 4):

The stack exchange system is a democracy, five people voted to close your question for whatever reasons they chose, that gets it closed, simple as that. It's the same on movies.se, stackoverflow, all of them.

Not sure you're banned though, don't know where you get that from...

Comment: One of the bad things about the heuristic based autoban system is that mods have no visibility into it. I can't see if someone is banned, nor can I reverse it.

Comment: I can't see why the OP would be Q banned either.

Comment: It's not a democracy; in this respect it's an oligarchy (well, you could argue it's a meritocracy I suppose). Only a small fraction of users can vote to close questions.

Comment: @einpkklum, I'm sorry but you're being offensive, you need to EARN 3000 reputation to be able to vote to close, there are over 3,500 users who can do so out of an active, repeated-use community of around 12,000 - so that's hardly a tiny minority - but everyone who CAN vote has put time and effort into this site and importantly understand what it's for and how it works. Any other opinion you may have is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't vote to close this question, but I probably would have, if I had seen it.

Here's why:

The essential answer to this question is:

> Move MySQL to a new server. Tell your application to connect to MySQL at the name or address of the new server.

Neither the question nor the answer provide you or anyone else any real help, since the specifics of *how* you do either of these two steps will vary depending on your environment and your application, so they are unanswerable as is.

Most likely your next question would be something like: "How do I tell WordPress/Drupal/whatever where I moved MySQL to?" That *would* be answerable, and I wouldn't vote to close such a question. But this should have been in your original question as it's a critical detail to understanding and providing the answer you really need.

As it stands, then, the question fails the "ambiguous" and "incomplete" tests. It can be improved by explaining what you are really trying to do, the environment you are in, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you are unable to post questions and get the message:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account

Then you should look at [this meta.SF answer](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/3932/6177) and follow the link to the meta.SO answer to find out how to get un-banned.

I use "Not a Real Question" for vague or overly broad questions.  I don't think that applies to your question, but I'd say it's close to "Not Constructive:" there are multiple possible answers, not just one correct or best answer.