# remove ban on asking question but Locked questions

Tags: discussion, support

I want to remove my ban on asking questions so I have to edit my questions but my questions are locked and no more edited. They are useless for community but they are not going to delete. Now How I can ask questions and contribute to community ?

Comment: Only _you_ can get your ban removed and you have been provided with information on how to go about doing this already http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3930/how-can-i-remove-my-ban-on-asking-questions.

Answer (score 3):

I unlocked the two locked questions. Be warned, they were locked because you were attempting to deface the posts. Attempting to do so again will get them locked again, and your account suspended.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on how exactly the "Automatic Low-Quality Question/Answer Ban" works, so I don't know if you are blocked from *both* answering questions and asking, or if it's only asking.

If you are able to post answers, then you can work towards getting un-banned by providing some answers and earning some reputation.

My understanding is that one downvoted question isn't enough to get hit by the auto-ban, so: did you delete some of your own questions?  If so, you can also work on those, and either un-delete them or flag them for moderator attention and ask if they can be undeleted.

For the one and only question I can see in your profile (which is locked), since you've asked about it here, a moderator will either unlock it or will likely post something to tell you what you'd have to do to get it unlocked.  In general, the way to handle something like that is to flag it and provide a short note for the moderators with your request.  e.g. "Please unlock this so I can edit it to make it better."

Comment: The heuristics behind the bans are not known outside of SE.