# Why am I not able to ask any more questions?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

I am a young programmer being paid to do some sysadmin work. I am active on stackoverflow, and so when I had a question, I came to serverfault. I asked three questions. Each recieved one downvote, and one got closed. Now I can't ask any more questions. I disagree that I should lose the ability to ask so quickly. What can be done about this?

Comment: Some advice for a young programmer being paid to do sysadmin work: speak to the people paying you and ask them to provide some basic education on the tools they are expecting you to use. This may sound harsh but your skills are way below those required to do the job you are being expected to do and this is not the kind of thing that you can easily learn on the job without a good grounding in the basics.