# Why I cannot ask question in ServerFault while I have no downvoted questions or issues?

Tags: discussion

I know I might be given huge downvotes for this question (but please be kind to me), but may I know the reason why I cannot ask in ServerFault?

I see my questions none of them are downvoted and my last question was for about two months ago.

Do you see any issues in my questions or the reason why I can't ask?

Answer (score 2):

You have 11 questions in total.  6 of them are closed.  5 of them are deleted, all of the deleted questions have downvotes.

Question bans and what you might be able to do about them are explained in the answer to this question:

[How can I remove my ban on asking questions?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3930/how-can-i-remove-my-ban-on-asking-questions)

Comment: But I see among my 6 questions, 2 of them are closed. And may I know the count of downvotes of deleted questions? I cannot see them.

Comment: 4 of the 5 deleted questions are closed, most for being off-topic.  Each deleted question has one downvote.