# I can't ask question in serverfault

Tags: support

I can't ask in serverfault, I read the docs about how to question.

How can I unlock asking question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a total of 13 questions on Server Fault, 7 of them are deleted.  You are blocked from asking questions by a site-wide (all of Stack Exchange) filter.  Information on how you can get out of the block are in this post and the linked meta.SE post.

[How can I remove my ban on asking questions?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3930/how-can-i-remove-my-ban-on-asking-questions)